# Affects on Facebook app permissions for changing app admin

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

I have a Facebook developer account under which there is a live app that is using the messenger platform. I have gone through the app review process for some of the permissions that are required for the app and already have those permissions approved. Some of those permissions are *pages_messaging*, *manage_pages*, etc.

Now I want to change the app owner. I know I can do this by changing the app roles. I can add a new admin from the dashboard. Then I can change the current admin account role to either developer or tester.

My question is if I change the app admin will it impact the already approved permissions? I mean, should I have to ask for these permissions again to be approved. Or will it work as it is? The app review process is time-consuming and it would be great if I can skip doing the same things again.

Also added this question to the Facebook developers community. https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/201102384688228/

Thank you

Comment: This should not affect what permissions/features were already approved. But your new app admin might have to go through the Individual Verification process with their account. (If the app is not tied to a business, and that business is already verified.)

Comment: Thanks, @CBroe I added a new admin. Then I tried changing the current admin role to tester and this action didn't impact the already approved permissions. The new app-admin didn't have to go through any Individual Verification process either. Because the app is tied to a verified business account.